How to force git to make a commit every time I merge two branches?
When there is no conflict, git does not make a commit when merging two branches.
However, I would like it to force it to do so. Is there a way to add a config line in the git config file in such a way that whenever two branches are merged, a commit is made?

I think you have a misunderstanding here. Git doesn't make a commit when there's conflicts. It does so when it cannot fast-forward a branch. If you do not want a fast-forward merge, use git merge --no-ff

Oh, I just noticed this is a duplicate :-/ Closing...

You can set it in config with
git config merge.ff false

It will disallow fast-forward merges and create a merge commit each time you do a merge.
(And as @evolutionxbox rightfully noted in comments, it's unrelated to conflicts.)
